Boot Failure Fedora emergency mode : Failed to mount boot-efi.mount - /boot/efi
I'm on a Dell XPS 13 with a dual boot Fedora 38 and Windows 11. Usually, when I start my computer from the grub menu, I either choose to start Fedora 6.5.8 or start Windows.
Grub booting selection menu:

One time without any change, when I booted my Fedora, the booting failed, saying that the OS version (Fedora Linux 38 (Xfce) dracut-059-4.fc38 (Initramfs)) is past its end-of-support date. And therefore I am in emergency mode.
When doing systemctl reboot I get to the same point.
When doing either systemctl default or exit I get a couple of failure with the first one being:
Failed to mount boot-efi.mount - /boot/efi.

Failures when trying 'systemctl default':

System configurations: cat /etc/fstab; lsblk; blkid;

From what I understood, it is probably because the fsck.vfat is not installed.
But from the emergency mode, I cannot install anything as I don't have a network connection.
If more information is needed I could provide the full journalctl and dmesg log, but they are both very long.
